# Laravel 4 Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I use the following rules for validation on creating a new user:

```
protected $rules= [
    'name'    => 'required',
    'email'    => [
        'required',
        'unique:user',
        'email'
    ]
];
```

When updating an existing user I use the same ruleset as shown above
but don't want a validation error if the user didn't change his email at all.

I currently resolve this by using the following:

```
if (!User::changed('email')) {
    unset($user->email);
}
```

It feels like a dirty workaround to me so I was wondering if there are better alternatives.

Also note that the `changed` method is something I wrote myself. Does anyone know if there
is a native Laravel 4 method for checking whether a model property has changed?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi check this my answer in this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976207/laravel-4-validation-uniquedatabase-ignore-current][1], i hope this help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976207/laravel-4-validation-uniquedatabase-ignore-current

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unique validation rule allows to ignore a given ID, which in your case is the ID of the data set you are updating.

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,10'
```

http://four.laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

Comment: BTW, I solve this by using a placeholder `:id:` in my validation rules and then process the rules before validating: https://github.com/betawax/role-model/blob/master/src/Betawax/RoleModel/RoleModel.php#L86-L101

Comment: I like the idea of using a placeholder but I'm not really convinced by your approach. Any thoughts on my 'second' question concerning a change state? I found some references in Laravel 3's source about a changed method but haven't found it so far in Laravel 4

Comment: In my code example, I replace the placeholder with `$this->getKey()` which is available for new *and* existing data sets. So you don't have to care about whether you are creating a new or updating an existing model. Just replace the placeholder on every save event. You can either do this by overwriting Eloquent's `save()` method or by using [model events](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events).

Comment: Addendum: I think you can use Eloquent's mutators (setters) to check whether your model property has changed. http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Could you be perhaps be a little more specific on the mutators subject? I can't think of a way to implement them as a global propertyIsChanged type of method.

Comment: @HolgerWeis Your placeholder method worked great for me, thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to create a validation function in the model and call it with the controller passing in the input, scenario and id (to ignore).

```
public function validate($input, $scenario, $id = null)
{
    $rules = [];

    switch($scenario)
    {
        case 'store':
            $rules   = [
                'name'     => 'required|min:5|unique:users',
                'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed'
            ];
            break;

        case 'update';
            $rules   = [
                'name'     => 'required|min:5|unique:users' .',name,' . $id,
                'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users' .',email,' . $id,
                'password' => 'min:4|confirmed'
            ];
            break;
    }

    return Validator::make($input, $rules);
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
    $input      = Input::all();
    $validation = $user->validate($input, 'update', $user->id);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Validation passes
        // Do other stuff
    }
```

As others mentioned, the 3rd parameter of the unique rule specifies an id to ignore. You can add other cases, such as 'login' to reuse the validation function.

Alternatively, Jeffrey Way at [Tuts Premium has a great series of lessons in "What's New In Laravel 4"](https://tutsplus.com/course/whats-new-in-laravel-4/#validation) which includes a couple of other approaches to handling validation using services and listeners.

Comment: adding the validation rules to the model seems to be the right solution. imho it's dirty to add the parameter for store or update everytime. this post follows a similar solution http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12104 maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on http://four.laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

You can exclude the users own id

```
protected $rules= [
    'name'    => 'required',
    'email'    => [
        'required',
        'unique:user,email,THE_USERS_USER_ID',
        'email'
    ]
];
```

Comment: I know about the exclude parameter but I see no valid non-hackish way of injecting it into my ruleset hence the question.

Comment: Why do you consider this hackish?

Answer (score 1):

**As of 2014-01-14**, you can use `sometimes` attribute, I believe Taylor added them 2 days ago to Laravel 4.1

```
$v = Validator::make($data, array(
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
));
```

`sometimes` only validate input if it exists. this may or may not suit your exact scenario, if you don't have a default value for insert.

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 0):

I handle this sort of thing in my validator function. My validators array is setup as a class variable. I then do something like this:

```
public function validate() 
{
    //exclude the current user id from 'unqiue' validators
    if( $this->id > 0 )
    {
        $usernameUnique = 'unique:users,username,'.$this->id;
        $emailUnique = 'unique:users,email,'.$this->id;
        $apiUnique = 'unique:users,api_key,'.$this->id;
    }
    else
    {
        $usernameUnique = 'unique:users,username';
        $emailUnique = 'unique:users,email';
        $apiUnique = 'unique:users,api_key';
    }

    $this->validators['username'] = array('required', 'max:32', $usernameUnique);
    $this->validators['email'] = array('required', 'max:32', $emailUnique);
    $this->validators['api_key'] = array('required', 'max:32', $apiUnique);

    $val = Validator::make($this->attributes, $this->validators);

    if ($val->fails())
    {
        throw new ValidationException($val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by having different rules for update and create on models that need to do so, like Users.

I have a Model class that extends Eloquent, where I define the validation, and then all child models that extend the Model can have have both the **$rules** and **$update_rules** defined. If you define only $rules, it will be used both for create and update.

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
    protected $errors;
    protected static $rules = array();    
    protected $validator;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array(), Validator $validator = null) {
        parent::__construct($attributes);    
        $this->validator = $validator ?: \App::make('validator');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        # call validatie when createing
        static::creating(function($model) {
            return $model->validate();
        });

        # call validatie when updating with $is_update = true param
        static::updating(function($model) {
            return $model->validate(true);
        });
    }

    public function validate($is_update = false) {
        # if we have $update_rules defined in the child model, and save is an update
        if ($is_update and isset(static::$update_rules)) {
            $v = $this->validator->make($this->attributes, static::$update_rules);
        }
        else {
            $v = $this->validator->make($this->attributes, static::$rules);
        }

        if ($v->passes()) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->setErrors($v->messages());
        return false;
    }

    protected function setErrors($errors) {
        $this->errors = $errors;
    }

    public function getErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function hasErrors() {
        return ! empty($this->errors);
    }
}
```