# Laravel 4 Validation unique(database) ignore current

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm doing validation on a users edit form and have the validation checking if the username is unique in the database or not.

However when the editing a user and you don't change the username field it's still checking if the field is unique or not...

Is there a laravel way to ignore the current username if not changed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Should have read the docs more, of course laravel 4 does this...

#### What I had

```
$rules = array('username' => 'required|unique:users');
```

#### What I have

```
$rules = array('username' => 'required|unique:users,username,'.$id);
```

You can tell the validator to ignore a given ID like above.

Comment: You can also do $rules = array('username' => 'required|unique:users,username,{{$id}}');

Comment: There should be a better way to do this (and I think I've done it before, just can't remember). I hold every model rules on a `$rules` attribute and I want to automatically skip itself when checking for uniqueness while updating.

Answer (score 9):

This solution worked for me:

```
protected  $rules = array(
    'email' => "required|email|unique:users,email,:id",
);
```

Comment: This works well on Laravel 5.0. Using the ":id" notation means that you don't need to know what the id of the record is. It is particularly handy when validation rules are defined statically - in a config file or a static `$rules` array of an eloquent model, and there is nowhere in the code to pass in the updating record ID, even if you did know it at the point of validation.

Comment: This did not work for me out of the box, for this to work I think you should do something like [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-4-unique-validation-rules-not-working/replies/60695).

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 4.1, if you extend the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` class, override the `validateUnique()` method as such:

```
/**
 * Validate the uniqueness of an attribute value on a given database table.
 *
 * If a database column is not specified, the attribute will be used.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return bool
 */
protected function validateUnique($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $this->requireParameterCount(1, $parameters, 'unique');

    $table = $parameters[0];

    // The second parameter position holds the name of the column that needs to
    // be verified as unique. If this parameter isn't specified we will just
    // assume that this column to be verified shares the attribute's name.
    $column = isset($parameters[1]) ? $parameters[1] : $attribute;

    // If the specified ID column is present in the data, use those values; otherwise,
    // fall back on supplied parameters.
    list($idColumn, $id) = [null, null];
    if (isset($parameters[2])) {
        list($idColumn, $id) = $this->getUniqueIds($parameters);

        if (strtolower($id) == 'null') $id = null;
        else if (strtolower($id) == 'id' && isset($this->data[$idColumn])) $id = $this->data[$idColumn];
    }
    else if (isset($this->data['id'])) {
        $idColumn = 'id';
        $id = $this->data[$idColumn];
    }

    // The presence verifier is responsible for counting rows within this store
    // mechanism which might be a relational database or any other permanent
    // data store like Redis, etc. We will use it to determine uniqueness.
    $verifier = $this->getPresenceVerifier();

    $extra = $this->getUniqueExtra($parameters);

    return $verifier->getCount(

        $table, $column, $value, $id, $idColumn, $extra

    ) == 0;
}
```

In your validator rules, you could do this (will check for `id` field existing in validation data - this is the most generalized usage):

```
$rules = 'unique:model,field';
```

this (will check for `id` field existing in validation data) (equivalent to the above):

```
// specifying anything other than 'id' or 'null' as the 3rd parameter
// will still use the current behavior
$rules = 'unique:model,field,id';
```

or this (will check for `idColumn` field existing in validation data):

```
// specifying anything other than 'id' or 'null' as the 3rd parameter
// will still use the current behavior
$rules = 'unique:model,field,id,idColumn';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the validator as a service or copy the logic and apply that your need, like this

```
$valitator = MyCustomValidator::make()->on('update')->setCurrent($id);
```

check in: 
https://github.com/bradleySuira/laravel-context-validator/blob/master/examples/unique-on-update.php

Comment: Call to undefined method ::make()

Comment: Maybe is the namespace in the example is App\Services\Validators\EquipmentTypeValidator; you should add the use keyword