# Validating unique constraints in Laravel using the Ardent validation package

Tags: php, laravel-4, ardent

I am using *Ardent* in my Laravel application to provide record validation. Ardent uses a static `$rules` variable in your model to store your validation information, like so:

```
class Project extends Ardent{

    public static $rules = array
    (
        'name'        => 'required|max:40',
        'project_key' => 'required|max:10|unique:projects',
    );

}
```

Ardent will use these same rules on any saving event, however the `unique:projects` rule requires a third parameter upon updating a record so that it doesn't validate against the current record. I would normally do this in my controller like so:

```
class ProjectController{

    ...

    public function update( $id ){

        $record = $this->projects->findById($id);
        $record::$rules['project_key'] += ',' . $record->id;
        if( $record->update(Input::get(array('name','project_key'))) )
        {
            ...
        }
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors( $record->errors() );
    }

    ...

}
```

To cut down on the amount of duplicated code I have moved the code for identifying if the record exists and error handling for when it doesn't to another class method that sets `$this->project` to the current project but now updating the models static `$rules` property is problematic because the below cant work:

```
...

    public function update( $id ){

        if ( ! $this->identifyProject( $id ) ){
            return $this->redirectOnError;
        }

        $this->project::$rules['project_key'] += ',' . $this->project->id;

        ...

    }

...
```

How would you go about updating the static `$rules`? Should I, rather than doing so in the controller do something on a model event or is there a method in ardent that I am missing that updates the unique constraints before validation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16976208/2962442 unique constraint got 3 parameters, read more about it

Comment: @kmlnvm that question refers to using the default laravel validation, I know how to use it, and am doing so via ardent. I am more interested in how to modify a classes public static variable when it is itself set to a public variable within another class and accessed via `$this`

Comment: instead of editing static variable create method `rules` with parameter, that will return "compiled" rules

Comment: Static methods are global - you cannot change the state of `$rules` property for just the instance stored in `$this->project`. Instead you must change the property globaly: `Project::$rules['project_key']...`

Comment: @kmlnvm thank you, your comment prompted me to check if ardent had a method that did just that, and it does.

Comment: @steve thank you for that, helped clear up the confusion. I hadn't had my morning coffee when I was trying to sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in my question, that I overlooked the fact that ardent has a `updateUniques` method, which is to be used in place of `update` for when you have unique constraints in your rules. Therefore my initial code example becomes:

```
class ProjectController{

    ...

    public function update( $id ){

        if ( ! $this->identifyProject( $id ) ){
            return $this->redirectOnError;
        }

        $this->project->fill(Input::only(array('name','project_key')));

        if( $this->project->updateUniques() )
        {
            return Redirect::route('project.edit', $this->project->id)
                ->with('success', 'Your changes have been saved.');
        }
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors( $this->project->errors() );
    }

    ...

}
```