# Laravel conditional uniqueness validator doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I want to validate that the `name` field in the database table `pools` is unique. When I'm creating a new entry, this works fine:

```
$rules = [
    'name' => 'required|unique:pools'
];
```

However, when I want to update an existing record, then the uniqueness check should skip the item being updated (as, obviously, the name could be unchanged). So I dug around and found this option:

```
$rules = [
    'name' => 'required|unique:pools,id,1'
];
```

Where 1 is the ID of the record I'm updating. This seemed to resolve the issue, but then I tested with a different ID (in which case the validator should return an error) but it still allows a new record with the same `name` to be added.

For example, if I do

```
$rules = [
    'name' => 'required|unique:pools,id,4'
];
```

Where 4 is an ID of a completely different entry in the DB (or even an ID that doesn't exist at all), the uniqueness check doesn't work and allows me to make as many duplicate records as I want. It would seem that adding any ID to the above rule makes the validator ignore all matches in the DB, except just the one with the given ID.

Basically, I have a similar problem to the one outlined in this question, except the answer doesn't work for me:

[Laravel 4 Validation unique(database) ignore current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976207/laravel-4-validation-uniquedatabase-ignore-current)

Anyone with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second parameter is the field, what you are looking for the be unique. Change id, to name. Third parameter is the id, which the lookup have to skip.

```
$rules = [
   'name' => 'required|unique:pools,mame,4'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a silly mistake,try this

```
$rules = [
'name' => 'required|unique:pools,name,4'
];
```

Comment: Haha ,that was quick :)

Comment: I see. Silly indeed. Will accept the answer that came 2 seconds earlier I guess, since they're both the same.

Comment: @jovan Please accept one of them,it will helpful for another who will face this problem